# Opening a Jupyter Notebook from Python Script on Windows cmd line

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a simple tkinter GUI with a dropdown, that when selected, runs a function. I know the anaconda prompt and cmd line are different, however, I can't get the command to work inside the python script without using the external batch file.

I am reading from a folder of csv files to get the list and all that is fine.

Currently, this works:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

folder = 'C:/Users/[user]/Desktop'

OptionList = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder) if fname.endswith('.csv')]

app = tk.Tk()

app.geometry('500x200')

variable = tk.StringVar(app)
variable.set(OptionList[0])

opt = tk.OptionMenu(app, variable, *OptionList)
opt.config(width=500, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")

def callback(*args):
    os.system('cmd /k "C:\\Users\\[user]\\Desktop\\notebook_launch.bat"')
    app.destroy()

variable.trace("w", callback)
app.mainloop()
```

Here is the working batch file:

```
@echo on
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
voila "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\notebook.ipynb"
```

When I try to execute the commands from windows cmd, if I use `/k` instead of `/c` to keep the window open, I can see that the anaconda prompt opens, however the next line of code does not execute.

Attempt at getting both commands to run in the script:

```
def callback(*args):
    os.system('cmd /c "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"')
    os.system('cmd /c "voila C:\\Users\\[user]\\Documents\\notebook.ipynb"')
    app.destroy()
```

Alternate attempt, same result:

```
def callback(*args):
    os.system('cmd /c "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat" && "voila C:\\Users\\[user]\\Documents\\notebook.ipynb"')
    app.destroy()
```

Noted above, I have also tried using `&&` to combine the commands in one line, but same result, only the anaconda prompt opens and the "voila" command does not execute.

Anyone know what I'm missing or if it possible? My guess is that since the (base) prompt is opening, the `os.system` function doesn't know what to do with the anaconda prompt. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Turns out I just needed to pause the execution for half a second, as it was executing too quickly. By adding `import time` and squeezing `time.sleep(.5)` between the two lines, everything functioned perfectly.

Functioning code:

```
import time

def callback(*args):
    os.system('cmd /c "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"')
    time.sleep(.5)
    os.system('cmd /c "voila C:\\Users\\[user]\\Documents\\notebook.ipynb"')
    app.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to pause the execution for half a second, as it was executing too quickly. By adding import time and squeezing time.sleep(.5) between the two lines, everything functioned perfectly.

Functioning code:

```
import time

def callback(*args):
    os.system('cmd /c "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"')
    time.sleep(.5)
    os.system('cmd /c "voila C:\\Users\\[user]\\Documents\\notebook.ipynb"')
    app.destroy()
```